# Vim script Gundo isn't working properly

Tags: ubuntu, vim, vim-plugins

I'm having trouble with my vim with "python" support.

I had installed gnome-vim, in Ubuntu 11.04, that theoretically has "python" support but if I install [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) and [gundo](http://sjl.bitbucket.org/gundo.vim/), when I press F5, the message below is shown:

```
Error detected while processing /home/perseus/Coding/LinuxConfigFiles/.vim/bundle/gundo/autoload/gundo.vim:
line   22:
E837: This Vim cannot execute :py3 after using :python
line   30:
E121: Undefined variable: s:has_supported_python
E15: Invalid expression: !s:has_supported_python
Error detected while processing function gundo#GundoToggle..<SNR>26_GundoToggle..<SNR>26_GundoOpen:
line    2:
E121: Undefined variable: s:has_supported_python
E15: Invalid expression: s:has_supported_python == 2
line   10:
E121: Undefined variable: s:has_supported_python
"__Gundo_Preview__" [New File]
Error detected while processing function gundo#GundoToggle..<SNR>26_GundoToggle..<SNR>26_GundoOpen..<SNR>26_GundoRenderGraph:
line    1:
E121: Undefined variable: s:has_supported_python
E15: Invalid expression: s:has_supported_python == 2
Error detected while processing function gundo#GundoToggle..<SNR>26_GundoToggle..<SNR>26_GundoOpen..<SNR>26_GundoRenderPreview:
line    1:
E121: Undefined variable: s:has_supported_python
E15: Invalid expression: s:has_supported_python == 2
```

Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Seems almost like your vim wasn't complied with python support.

Comment: `:version` will tell you if you have `+python`. If yes, maybe it's compiled against a different version of python.

Comment: That is the point: I typed `:version` and got `+python/dyn` and `+python3/dyn`. Do you have a tutorial how to compile with python support on the internet? I didn't find how to compile to ubuntu/linux with python support.

Comment: I found the [problem](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/if_pyth.html#python-dynamic) on vim documentation. The problem is that I don't know do the work around =/.

Comment: @André, there's nothing wrong with your Vim—`python/dyn` means you *have* Python support. The problem is with Gundo itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I'm supposing a debian like environment**

1. Get [vim source](http://www.vim.org/download.php).
   I downloaded the source using mercurial. If you don't have it installed:

   > apt-get install mercurial

   Then, get the source using mercurial

   `hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com/hg/ ~/vimpy2.7`
2. Had python 2.7 installed and python library

   > apt-get install python python-dev
3. Compile using the following command

   > cd ~/vimpy2.7
   >   ./configure --with-features=huge --enable-pythoninterp --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config
4. Install

   > make
   >   make install

Observation: It's necessary be root to run `make install`

If everything works, the vim must be installed at /usr/local/vim.
type ./usr/local/vim, type inside vim `:version` and verify `+python`

Comment: $ hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com/hg/ .
abort: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Comment: I pulled the code from here: `https://github.com/vim/vim.git`

Answer (score 3):

To get it working these days (with python3 support) you need to add the following variable to your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:gundo_prefer_python3 = 1
```

Otherwise you'll run into errors like: "E117: Unknown function: gundo#GundoShow"

Answer (score 0):

I got the same errors as you.

Apparently, a [recent change](https://github.com/sjl/gundo.vim/commit/b1a9bae565d66c317c2968e7bd4f76871b95d7e5) to Gundo enabling Python 3 support has broken it.

[Strahinja Marković](https://github.com/Valloric/) has forked Steve Losh' repo and [pull-requested the fix](https://github.com/sjl/gundo.vim/pull/17). At least until Steve fixes the bug, I suggest you use [Strahinja's repo](https://github.com/Valloric/gundo.vim) instead—it works fine for me.